# Can't assign value to 2d array object member

Tags: c++

```
const int MAP_WIDTH = 100;
const int MAP_HEIGHT = 100;
const int RANDOM_POINTS = 10;
const int seeds = 3;

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int tileIndex;
};

Point* points = new Point[RANDOM_POINTS];
Point* mapPoints[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];

Point* nearestPoint(int x, int y)
{
    Point* ptr;
    ptr = points;
    Point* nearest_point;
    int nearest_dis = 1000;
    int distance;
    for (int i = 0; i < RANDOM_POINTS; i++, ptr++)
    {
        int dx = ptr->x;
        int dy = ptr->y;
        distance = abs(dx - x) + abs(dy - y);
        if (distance < nearest_dis)
        {
            nearest_point = ptr;
            nearest_dis = distance;
        }
    }

    return nearest_point;
}

int main(int argc,char* args[])
{
    srand(seeds);
    int min = 25;
    int max = 75;
    for (int i = 0; i < RANDOM_POINTS; i++)
    {       
        points[i].x = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
        points[i].y = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
        points[i].tileIndex = rand() & 6;
    }

    std::ofstream mapFile;
    //mapFile.open("res/mapFile.map",std::ios::app);

    for (int px = 0; px < MAP_WIDTH; px++)
    {
        for (int py = 0 ; px < MAP_HEIGHT; py++)
        {
            mapPoints[px][py]->x = px;
            mapPoints[px][py]->y = py;
            mapPoints[px][py]->tileIndex = nearestPoint(mapPoints[px][py]->x, mapPoints[px][py]->y)->tileIndex;
            std::cout << mapPoints[px][py]->x << mapPoints[px][py]->y << std::endl;
            /*if(px<MAP_WIDTH-1)
                mapFile << mapPoints[px][py]->tileIndex << ",";
            else
                mapFile << mapPoints[px][py]->tileIndex << "\n";*/      
        }
    }
    mapFile << std::endl;
    mapFile.close();
    //std::cout << nearestPoint(3, 3)->tileIndex << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`points[RANDOM_POINTS]` store random generated points .

`mapPoints[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT]` is map size .

The purpose of this code is output random generated tile type index to a text file ,so I can use it with tileset.png file .

But I find out the 2d array `mapPoints[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT]` is empty .Failed to assign value to data member x ,y ,index .
  I don't know where is the problem .

Comment: `Point* mapPoints[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];` is an array of pointers, not an array of points. There is no memory behind the pointers.

Comment: Thanks .Should I just use 2d array ,not pointer ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Point* mapPoints[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
...
 mapPoints[px][py]->x = px;
```

`mapPoints` is an array of pointers. The pointers does not point anywhere. As the `mapPoints` is a global variable, it is initialized with `nullptr`. `nullptr` is invalid pointer, dereferencing it `mapPoints[px][py]->x` is undefined behavior and most probably causes something similar to "segmentation fault" or other strange fault.

You need to have the memory, not pointers, if you want to store something.

```
Point mapPoints[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
...
 mapPoints[px][py].x = px;
```

Also in this line:

```
Point* points = new Point[RANDOM_POINTS];
```

you are allocating `RANDOM_POINTS` points. But you never `delete` them. This leaks memory. Just do:

```
Point points[RANDOM_POINTS];
```